# Prove that there is a $\Delta_1$-set $E$ which satisfies $S_0 \setminus S_1 \subset E \subset S_0$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, recursion, computability

I'd appreciate some help for the following exercise. $\Sigma_1, \Pi_1$ and $\Delta_1$ are defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy
I think I can prove 2. when I have 1. - can someone give me hint, how to start with the proof? I already know that all $\Sigma_1$-sets are r.e. and all $\Pi_1$-sets are co-r.e. and  all $\Delta_1$-sets are recursive.

1. Assume $S_0, S_1 \subset \mathbb{N}$ are $\Sigma_1$-sets which satisfy $S_0 \cup S_1 = \mathbb{N}$. Prove that there is a $\Delta_1$-set $E$ such that $S_0 \setminus S_1 \subset E \subset S_0$ is satisfied.
2. Assume $Q_0, Q_1 \subset \mathbb{N}$ are $\Pi_1$-sets which satisfy $S_0 \cap S_1 = \emptyset$. Prove that there is a $\Delta_1$-set $E$ such that $Q_0 \subset E$ and $Q_1 \subset \mathbb{N} \setminus E$ are satisfied.

EDIT:

I'm trying to construct $\Pi_1$ and $\Sigma_1$ formulas for $E$:

$\exists k \varphi_0(k,n),\exists k \varphi_1(k,n)$ are $\Sigma_1$  formulas which define $S_0$ and $S_1$.

$S_0=\{n\in \mathbb{N}: \mathbb{N}\vDash \exists k ~ \varphi_0(k,n)\}$

$S_1=\{n\in \mathbb{N}: \mathbb{N}\vDash \exists k ~ \varphi_1(k,n)\}$

$S_0\setminus S_1=\{n\in \mathbb{N}: \mathbb{N}\vDash \exists k ~ \varphi_0(k,n) \land \forall l ~ \lnot \varphi_1(l,n)\}$

$E=\{n\in \mathbb{N}: \mathbb{N}\vDash \exists k ~ \varphi_0(k,n) \land \exists l ~ \lnot \varphi_1(l,n)\}$

$\exists k ~ \varphi_0(k,n) \land \exists l ~ \lnot \varphi_1(l,n)$ is equivalent to a $\Sigma_1$ formula. Now I need a $\Sigma_1$ formula for $\mathbb{N} \setminus E$ or a $\Pi_1$ formula for $E$. Can someone give me a hint how to find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the intuition: We know any natural number is in $S_0$ or in $S_1.$ So given $n\in\mathbb N,$ recursively enumerate $S_0$ and $S_1$ side by side. If $n$ appears first in the $S_1$ enumeration, $n\notin E,$ whereas if it appears first in the $S_0$ enumeration, $n\in E.$ (And break ties however.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So I can basically give a recursive characteristic function $\chi_E$ for $E$: 

$\chi_E(x)=1$ if $x \in S_0$ or $x \in S_0 \cap S_1$

$\chi_E(x)=0$ else.

This function is recursive because there is an algorithm which holds in finite time if $x \in S_0$or $x \in S_1$. Hence $E$ is a $\Delta_1$-set which also satisfies the condition $S_0 \setminus S_1 \subset E \subset S_0$.

Comment: Do you have suggestions how to formalize what I wrote?

Comment: No, $E$ probably only contains *some* of $S_0\cap S_1$ (whichever happen to appear in the enumeration of $S_0$ before they appear in the enumeration of $S_1$). Yes, $E$ is defined in terms of some fixed recursive enumerations of the two sets, and the definition is in the form of an algorithm that decides membership in $E$ based on these, so $E$ is recursive. Not sure how formal you have to be here. If you wish, you can avoid arguments about recursiveness and use the idea I gave to write down a $\Delta_1$ formula based on the $\Sigma_1$ formulas defining $S_0$ and $S_1.$

Comment: Okay, I see what's wrong in my comment above. What do you mean by $\Delta_1$ formula? For a $\Delta_1$-set there is a $\Sigma_1$-formula and $\Pi_1$-formula which defines it, or am I mistaken?
But maybe I can do just that, writing down both for $E$.

Comment: A lot of times these things are defined up to equivalence, so a $\Delta_1$ formula is one that’s equivalent to a $\Sigma_1$ and a $\Pi_1$ formula (where those are equivalent to formulas that take the standard syntactic forms). But I think it’s probably best to do what you have in mind: find both a $\Pi_1$ formula that defines $E$ and a $\Sigma_1$ formula that defines $E.$

Comment: I added some of my thoughts to my question. Could you share your thoughts about it? Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: It doesn't seem like you're grasping what $E$ is. The logic above suggests that $E$ should be defined by something like $\exists k (\varphi_0(k,n)\land \forall (l< k)\lnot\varphi_1(l,n))$ (i.e. it appears in $S_0$ before (or same time as) it appears in $S_1$). And the complement of $E$ can be defined something like $\exists k(\varphi_1(k,n)\land \forall (l\le k) \lnot \varphi_0(l,n)$ (i.e. it appears in $S_1$ before it appears in $S_0$). That the former is equivalent to the negation of the latter will require the fact that $\forall n(\exists k \varphi_0(k,n)\lor \exists k \varphi_1(k,n))$